# Search not working in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, laravel-5.1

I am currently doing a project. In this project I cant do my search form working.My search button not showing any value. It just returned an empty page. Please Help Me. My Route is

```
Route::get('/search', array('as' =>'search' ,'uses' => 'UserController@search'));
```

My Blade Template is

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                   <div class="social">
                        <ul class="social-share">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="search">
                            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'search', 'method'=> 'GET']) !!}

                                <input type="text" class="search-form" name="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search">

                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>

                            {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </div><!--/.top-bar-->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{!! URL::route('home') !!}">{!! Html::image('images/logo.png','logo') !!}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li <?php if($active == 'home') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="{!! URL::route('home') !!}">Home</a></li>

                    <li <?php if($active == 'about_us') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="{!! URL::route('about_us') !!}">About Us</a></li>

                    <li <?php if($active == 'hospital') {echo 'class="active"';} ?> class="dropdown" >
                        <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hospitals <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @foreach($divisions as $division)

                                <li><a href="{!! URL::route('district', $division['id']) !!}">{{ $division['name'] }}</a></li>

                            @endforeach 

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li <?php if($active == 'doctor') {echo 'class="active"';} ?> class="dropdown" >
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Doctors <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        @foreach($divisions as $division)
                                <li><a href="{!! URL::route('districts',$division['id']) !!}">{{ $division->name }}</a></li>

                            @endforeach 

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li <?php if($active == 'contact') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="{!! URL::route('contact') !!}">Contact Us</a></li>

                    <li <?php if($active == 'login') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="{!! URL::route('login') !!}">Login</a></li> 

                    <li <?php if($active == 'register') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="{!! URL::route('register') !!}">Sign Up</a></li>                           
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </nav><!--/nav-->

</header><!--/header-->
```

My Controller is

```
public function search(Request $req)
    {

        $divisions = Division::all();
        $doctors = Doctor::orderBy('name');
        $name = $req->input('name');
        if(!empty($name)) {
             $doctors->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $name . '%');
        }
        $doctors=$doctors->paginate(1);
       return view('users.index')
                   ->with('divisions',$divisions)
                   ->with('doctors',$doctors);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution of the problem is

```
public function search(Request $req)
    {

   $divisions = Division::all();
   $name = $req->input('search');

   $doctors = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $name . '%')->get();

   return view('users.search')
               ->with('divisions',$divisions)
                ->with('doctors',$doctors);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in route you can write it like this use post method for passing the search keyword

```
    Route::post('/search', 'UserController@search_bar')->name('search');
```

After that in your blade template do a little modification in blade template

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'search']) !!}

   <input type="text" class="search-form" name="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search">

   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>  {!! Form::submit($btnTxt,array('class'=>'btn btn-success')) !!} {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Now in your controller try it mine since you have not mentioned in which model you're searching so I will just show you one way and you can grab it and try it on your own,

```
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
    $name = $request->input('search');
    if(null !== $name)
    {
         $doctors = App\Doctor::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $name .'%')->paginate(10);
  return view('users.index',compact('doctors'));
    }else{
      return redirect()->back();
     }
```

}

Be sure you're pointing to right view path, cheers mate it will work for you for sure :)

Comment: sorry your code does not work. It shows nothing @Roshan Ranabhat

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `$req->input('name')` yet you have called it `search` in your form; `name="search"`.

Either change your input to this:

```
<input type="text" class="search-form" name="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search">
```

Or your controller request to:

```
$name = $req->input('search');
```

It also looks like your form is missing a submit button?

```
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

Comment: @Jahid26 did you try what I suggested?